# Android - styling seek bar

Tags: android, android-seekbar, custom-selectors, android-slider

I wanted to style a seek bar which looks like the one in the image below.

[image]

By using default seekbar I will get something like this:

[image]

So what I need is to only change the color. I need no extra styles. Is there any straight forward approach to do this or should I build my custom drawable.?

I tried building custom one, but I could not get the exact one as shown above.
After using custom drawable, what I get is as shown below:

[image]

If I need to build the custom one, then please suggest how to reduce the width of the progress line and also the shape.

my custom implementation:

background_fill.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FF555555"
        android:endColor="#FF555555"
        android:startColor="#FF555555" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

progress_fill.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:centerColor="#FFB80000"
        android:endColor="#FFFF4400"
        android:startColor="#FF470000" />

    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#50999999" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#70555555" />

</shape>
```

progress.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/background_fill"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/progress_fill" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

thumb.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >

    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:endColor="#E5492A"
        android:startColor="#E5492A" />

    <size
        android:height="20dp"
        android:width="20dp" />

</shape>
```

seekbar:

```
<SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBarDistance"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/progress"
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" >
    </SeekBar>
```

Comment: Thanks for showing a working seekbar style change example XD. (not many on the internet).

Answer (score 313, accepted):

I would extract drawables and xml from Android source code and change its color to red.
Here is example how I completed this for mdpi drawables:

Custom `red_scrubber_control.xml` (add to res/drawable):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_disabled_holo" android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_pressed_holo" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_focused_holo" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_control_normal_holo"/>
</selector>
```

Custom: `red_scrubber_progress.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_track_holo_light"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_secondary_holo"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <scale
            android:drawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_primary_holo"
            android:scaleWidth="100%" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Then copy required drawables from Android source code, I took [from this link](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/tree/ics-factoryrom-2-release/core/res/res)

It is good to copy these drawables for each hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi. For example I use only mdpi:

Then using Photoshop change color from blue to red:

red_scrubber_control_disabled_holo.png:
[image: red_scrubber_control_disabled_holo]

red_scrubber_control_focused_holo.png:
[image: red_scrubber_control_focused_holo]

red_scrubber_control_normal_holo.png:
[image: red_scrubber_control_normal_holo]

red_scrubber_control_pressed_holo.png:
[image: red_scrubber_control_pressed_holo]

red_scrubber_primary_holo.9.png:
[image: red_scrubber_primary_holo.9]

red_scrubber_secondary_holo.9.png:
[image: red_scrubber_secondary_holo.9]

red_scrubber_track_holo_light.9.png:
[image: red_scrubber_track_holo_light.9]

Add SeekBar to layout:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/red_scrubber_progress"
    android:thumb="@drawable/red_scrubber_control" />
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Andrew, thank you for the great answer. I'm having an issue with this. When using the `red_scrubber_control` drawable for the thumb, I run into a crash. If all of the drawables in the selector are the same, it works fine, but if I change one of them, I get a `Resources$NotFoundException: File .../red_scrubber_control.xml from drawaable resource ID...` Any thoughts?

Comment: Whoops. Turns out it was related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6669296/android-custom-button-state-selector-xml-file-causing-resourcenotfoundexception. The new image I was trying to add was accidentally 37MB instead of 2KB...

Comment: Is there anyway to use `@dimen` to set the size of the thumb based on the screen?

Comment: @SiKni8 You can define different dimension for different screen sizes based on normal, large, xlarge, sw or w parameters for values folder. Then simply use this dimension in your layout, style or theme. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)

Comment: So I shouldn't put the XML in the drawable folder than? Instead each drawable should be in the `sw` folder?

Comment: No keep your images only in drawable folders. Check this: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699951/changing-size-of-seekbar-thumb/18559778#18559778) I have added my answer there. All you need just to replace `40dp` with dimension value and create different values based on qualifiers.

Comment: I followed this instruction but the thumb just cuts off  here is the links to preview https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=FCE126A94D1D4820!19679&authkey=!AMH-DGnkxrj9Ap8&v=3

Comment: How to change the height of the progress same as to height of the thumb?

Comment: Thanks for the link to the Android Holo Colors Generator. That's very helpful.

Comment: @TintinabulatorZea Images that you are pointing is 9 patch images, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/help/draw9patch.html

Comment: 9-patch is the right solution. If use shape, will fail to show line on tablet for me.

Comment: Do you have the scrubber image in white colour?

Comment: use tool: http://android-holo-colors.com/ , select white color and toggle on seekbar it will generate all assets for you

Comment: For me adding **android:splitTrack="false"** to SeekBar solve transparency problem of thumb. [more detail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41693154/custom-seekbar-thumb-size-color-and-background)

Comment: This is how you can customize a SEEKBAR. Just watch this video - https://youtu.be/O48ahJPTvJc

Answer (score 126):

Android seekbar custom material style, for other seekbar customizations http://www.zoftino.com/android-seekbar-and-custom-seekbar-examples

```
<style name="MySeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">#f4511e</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">#388e3c</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTint">#c51162</item>
</style>
```

[image: seekbar custom material style]

Upd: `colorControlActivated` is `thumbTint` now.

Comment: Great solution for Android > 21

Comment: Are you sure that `colorControlActivated` is the right parameter for thumb? It should be `thumbTint`.

Comment: What is the solution for below API 21?

Comment: Set it like this: android:theme="@style/MySeekBar"

Comment: Nice explanation, but rather then search on SO, just follow material guidelines at  https://material.io/components/sliders#theming

Answer (score 75):

My answer is inspired from Andras Balázs Lajtha answer 
it allow to work without xml file

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: The progress dialog color changed but the thumbs color did not.. why?

Comment: If you don't need to do this in code and don't want to create layer lists and drawables etc you can also do this in the xml of the seekbar         ```android:progressTint="@color/my_color"
        android:thumbTint="@color/another_color"```

Comment: This is how you can Customize a SEEKBAR - Just watch this video.
https://youtu.be/O48ahJPTvJc

Answer (score 62):

If you want exactly the same bar but in red, you can add a PorterDuff color filter programatically. You can get each drawable that you want to colorize through the methods of the [ProgressBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html) base class. Then set a [color filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/PorterDuffColorFilter.html) for it.

```java
mySeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(srcColor, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```

If the wanted color adjustment can't be made through a Porter Duff filter, you can [specify your own color filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4354939/understanding-the-use-of-colormatrix-and-colormatrixcolorfilter-to-modify-a-draw).

Comment: not sure since which SDK, proly 21, but if you want to same icon just different color, just add the "colorAccent" color in colors.xml and it will use it

Answer (score 46):

Google have made this easier in SDK 21.  Now we have attributes for specifying the thumb tint colors:

```
android:thumbTint
android:thumbTintMode
android:progressTint
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#attr_android:thumbTint
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsSeekBar.html#attr_android:thumbTintMode

Comment: Tint lists apply to every UI element on Android as of API 21, it's how colorAccent gets applied.

Answer (score 45):

Just replace color atributtes with your color

background.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#D9D9D9"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

progress.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="line">

    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#2EA5DE"/>
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

style.xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_background"/>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip android:drawable="@drawable/seekbar_progress" />
    </item>

</layer-list>
```

thumb.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">

    <size android:height="30dp" android:width="30dp"/>
    <stroke android:width="18dp" android:color="#882EA5DE"/>
    <solid android:color="#2EA5DE" />
    <corners android:radius="1dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: How do I use the files in a seekbar?

Comment: @RahulRastogi how did you use these files? Kind of silly that this answer is so popular with 0 explanation of how it works...

Comment: @AssortedTrailmix I did it long time back. Try setting attributes like: 
        android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" and in android:progressDrawable property set the above mentioned layer list drawable file. You may try: https://mindfiremobile.wordpress.com/2014/05/20/seekbar-customization-for-android-development/

Answer (score 26):

All those answers are deprecated.

In 2019 it's easier to style your seekbar to your preferred color by changing your `ProgressBar` to this

```
<SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:progressTint="#36970f"
            android:thumbTint="#36970f"
            />
```

Styling your seekbar color programmatically try the following code

```
        seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
        seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Comment: Why deprecated?

Comment: because libraries have changed

Comment: You can see the answer of @Ahamadullah Saikat (https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074961/2914140) or https://www.lvguowei.me/post/customize-android-seekbar-color/. They don't use libraries and set SeekBar colors even for old APIs.

Comment: It seems to me that there should be one color regardless of the theme like

Answer (score 16):

For APIs < 21 (and >= 21) you can use the answer of [@Ahamadullah Saikat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50074961/2914140) or https://www.lvguowei.me/post/customize-android-seekbar-color/.

[image]

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="3dp"
    android:minHeight="3dp"
    android:progress="50"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seek_bar_ruler"
    android:thumb="@drawable/seek_bar_slider"
    />
```

drawable/seek_bar_ruler.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid
                android:color="#94A3B3" />
            <corners android:radius="2dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <solid
                    android:color="#18244D" />
                <corners android:radius="2dp" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

drawable/seek_bar_slider.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval"
    >

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="4dp"
        android:color="#18244D"
        />
    <size
        android:width="25dp"
        android:height="25dp"
        />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 14):

output:

[image]

Change Progress Color:

```
int normalColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.normal_color);
int selectedColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.selected_color);
Drawable normalDrawable = new ColorDrawable(normalColor);
Drawable selectedDrawable = new ColorDrawable(selectedColor);
ClipDrawable clipDrawable = new ClipDrawable(selectedDrawable, Gravity.LEFT, ClipDrawable.HORIZONTAL);
Drawable[] layers = {normalDrawable, clipDrawable, clipDrawable};
LayerDrawable seekbarDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
seekBar.setProgressDrawable(seekbarDrawable);
```

Change Thumb Color:

```
int thumbColor = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.thumb_color);
Drawable unwrappedDrawable = AppCompatResources.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.ic_seekbar_thumb);
assert unwrappedDrawable != null;
Drawable wrappedDrawable = DrawableCompat.wrap(unwrappedDrawable);
DrawableCompat.setTint(wrappedDrawable, thumbColor);
seekBar.setThumb(wrappedDrawable);
```

Comment: did not know AppCompat Seekbar existed

Answer (score 13):

Just set

```
android:maxHeight="3dp"
android:minHeight="3dp"
```

That's all

Answer (score 13):

```
<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:progressTint="@color/red"
android:thumbTint="@color/red" />
```

works Like same the answer selected. no need to make any drawable file or else.(IN 5.0 only)
Regards

Answer (score 12):

As mention one above (@andrew) , creating custom SeekBar is super Easy with this site - http://android-holo-colors.com/

Just enable SeekBar there, choose color, and receive all resources and copy to project.
Then apply them in xml, for example:

```
  android:thumb="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_control_selector_holo_light"
  android:progressDrawable="@drawable/apptheme_scrubber_progress_horizontal_holo_light"
```

Answer (score 8):

```
LayerDrawable progressDrawable = (LayerDrawable) mSeekBar.getProgressDrawable();

// progress bar line *progress* color
Drawable processDrawable = progressDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.progress);

// progress bar line *background* color
Drawable backgroundDrawable = progressDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.background);

// progress bar line *secondaryProgress* color
Drawable secondaryProgressDrawable = progressDrawable.findDrawableByLayerId(android.R.id.secondaryProgress);
processDrawable.setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

// progress bar line all color
mSeekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Color.BLUE, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);

// progress circle color
mSeekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 6):

By default, android will match the progress color of your slider to

```
`<item name="colorAccent">`
```

value in your **styles.xml**.  Then, to set a custom slider thumb image, just use this code in your **SeekBar** xml layout's block:

```
android:thumb="@drawable/slider"
```

Answer (score 4):

If you are using default SeekBar provided by android Sdk then their is a  simple way to change the color of that . just go to color.xml inside /res/values/colors.xml and change the colorAccent.

```
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#212121</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#1e1d1d</color>
     <!-- change below line -->
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 3):

Simple Way to change the seek bar color ...

```
 <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:theme="@style/Progress_color"/>
```

Style : Progress_color

```
 <style name="Progress_color">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item> <!-- Whatever color you want-->
</style>
```

java class change ProgressDrawable()

```
seek_bar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.white), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Answer (score 2):

I change the `background_fill.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >
<size android:height="1dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:centerColor="#616161"
    android:endColor="#616161"
    android:startColor="#616161" />
<corners android:radius="0dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#616161" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#616161" />
</shape>
```

and the `progress_fill.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="line" >
<size android:height="1dp" />
<gradient
    android:angle="0"
    android:centerColor="#fafafa"
    android:endColor="#fafafa"
    android:startColor="#fafafa" />
<corners android:radius="1dp" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#cccccc" />
<stroke
    android:width="1dp"
    android:color="#cccccc" />
 </shape>
```

to make the background & progress `1dp` height.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the Android resources, the seek bar actually use images.

You have to make a drawable which is transparent on top and bottom for say 10px and the center 5px line is visible.

Refer attached image. You need to convert it into a NinePatch.

[image]

Comment: can u please suggests some posts on the same?

Comment: One of the good links i found -

http://www.mokasocial.com/2011/02/create-a-custom-styled-ui-slider-seekbar-in-android/

Comment: Sunday G Akinsete's solution works, no need to use a NinePatch

Answer (score 1):

With the Material Component Library version 1.2.0 you can use the new [**`Slider`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) component.

```
 <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
       android:valueFrom="0"
       android:valueTo="300"
       android:value="200"
       android:theme="@style/slider_red"
       />
```

You can override the default color using something like:

```
  <style name="slider_red">
    <item name="colorPrimary">#......</item>
  </style>
```

[image]

Otherwise you can use these attribute in the layout to define a color or a color selector:

```
   <com.google.android.material.slider.Slider
       app:activeTrackColor="@color/...."
       app:inactiveTrackColor="@color/...."
       app:thumbColor="@color/...."
       />
```

or you can use a custom style:

```
 <style name="customSlider" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Slider">
    <item name="activeTrackColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="inactiveTrackColor">@color/....</item>
    <item name="thumbColor">@color/....</item>
  </style>
```

Comment: official docs are stating that its still planned. is there any other alternative?

Comment: @tejaspatel In the answer there is the [link](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/Slider.md) of the official component. The 1st version is now released in 1.2.0-alpha01.

Answer (score 1):

Now a days it becomes very easy, use material slider and use this to customize the color:

```
   app:thumbColor="@color/colorPrimary"
   app:trackColorInactive="@color/grey"
   app:trackColorActive="@color/colorPrimary"
```

Answer (score 1):

First Create A Drawble file using these steps

[image]

and name the drawble and specify Root element as layer-list -> click on OK. a new file custom_seekbar.xml will be created

[image]

Now in custom_seekbar.xml inside the layer-list add an item and give a shape to it. specify the color, height, corners of the SeekBar. Also, add another item of the same shape and size but you can change the color, left part of SeekBar’s thumb will be of this color.

[image]

Now again click on drawable -> new -> drawable resource file, name the file as thumb.xml and specify Root element as shape  -> click on OK. a new file thumb.xml will be created. Inside this file give the height, radius, and color of the thumb. these things can be changed. It totally depends upon how you want to design.

[image]

Now go to the activity_main.xml create a layout and inside the layout add a SeekBar. Specify the height width of SeekBar and the max progress that you want to use set progress to 0.

```
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" 
android:max="50"
android:progress="0"
```

This will create a customized Seekbar inside activity_main.xml.

[image]

Now open MainActivity.java class Declare objects of SeekBar and TextView,  inside onCreate method initialize both objects using findViewById() method. Perform an event of SeekBar change listener that will hold progress value, and by using this event set the progress value inside TextView.

```
   seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            // increment or decrement on process changed
            // increase the textsize
            // with the value of progress
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                value.setText(progress+"/"+"50");

                
            }..
```

[image]

Build and run the app. Put the thumb on Seekbar and move it either forward or backward it will display the process.

Code for the above implementation is given below:

Below is the code for the MainActivity.java file. Comments are added inside the code to understand the code in more detail.

```
    package com.abhi.customseekbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.SeekBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView value;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // initialize the seekBar object
        seekBar=findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
        value=findViewById(R.id.progress);
        // calling the seekbar event change listener
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            // increment or decrement on process changed
            // increase the textsize
            // with the value of progress
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                value.setText(progress+"/"+"50");           
            }
            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // This method will automatically
                // called when the user touches the SeekBar
            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // This method will automatically
                // called when the user
                // stops touching the SeekBar
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Below is the code for the activity_main.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="#458C85"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/Relative_1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_weight="2">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textViewSelectSizeOfArray"
            android:layout_width="273dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"

            android:layout_marginBottom="9dp"
            android:text="Custom Seek Bar"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="25dp" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:indeterminate="false"
            android:max="50"
            android:progress="0"
            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_seekbar"
            android:thumb="@drawable/thumb" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="199dp"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="0"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="30dp"
            android:textStyle="bold">

        </TextView>

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Below is the code for the custom_seekbar.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- color, size, shape height of seekbar -->
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="#605A5C"/>
            <size android:height="30dp"/>
            <corners android:radius="9dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <!-- color, size, shape height of seekbar when u drag it-->
    <item android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <scale android:scaleWidth="100%">
            <selector>
                <item android:state_enabled="false"
                    android:drawable="@color/purple_200"/>
                <item>
                    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                        <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
                        <size android:height="30dp"/>
                        <corners android:radius="9dp"/>
                    </shape>
                </item>
            </selector>
        </scale>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Below is the code for the thumb.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@color/purple_200"/>
    <size android:height="30dp" android:width="25dp"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who use Data Binding:

1. Add the following static method to any class

   ```
   @BindingAdapter("app:thumbTintCompat")
   public static void setThumbTint(SeekBar seekBar, @ColorInt int color) {
       seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
   }
   ```
2. Add `app:thumbTintCompat` attribute to your SeekBar

   ```
   <SeekBar
          android:id="@+id/seek_bar"
          style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          app:thumbTintCompat="@{@android:color/white}"
   />
   ```

That's it. Now you can use `app:thumbTintCompat` with any `SeekBar`. The progress tint can be configured in the same way.

**Note:** this method is also compatble with pre-lollipop devices.

Answer (score 0):

Small correction to the answer by @arnav-rao:

to make sure that the thumb is colored properly, use:

```
<style name="MySeekBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
    <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/colorBgTint</item>
    <item name="android:progressTint">@color/colorProgressTint</item>
    <item name="android:thumbTint">@color/colorThumbTint</item>
</style>
```

here android:thumbTint actually colors the "thumb"

Answer (score 0):

check this tutorial very good

https://www.lvguowei.me/post/customize-android-seekbar-color/

simple :

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/seekBar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="100"
                android:maxHeight="3dp"
                android:minHeight="3dp"
                android:progressDrawable="@drawable/seekbar_style"
                android:thumbTint="@color/positive_color"/>
```

then a style file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:id="@android:id/background">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid
                android:color="@color/positive_color" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:id="@android:id/progress">
        <clip>
            <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
                <solid
                    android:color="@color/positive_color" />
            </shape>
        </clip>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to create a style for the seekbar and then add the style to a theme so that I could have it applied to an entire theme while still allowing a substyle to override it. Here is what I did:

```
<!-- Blue App Theme -->
    <style name="AppTheme.Blue" parent="BaseTheme.Blue">        
        <item name="android:seekBarStyle">@style/SeekbarStyle.Blue</item>
        <item name="seekBarStyle">@style/SeekbarStyle.Blue</item> <!--This is essential for some devices, e.g. Samsung-->
</style>

<!-- Slider Styles -->
<style name="SeekbarStyle.Blue" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/material_blue_a700_pct_30</item>
        <item name="android:thumbTint">@color/material_blue_a700</item>
        <item name="android:thumbTintMode">src_in</item>
        <item name="android:progressTint">@color/material_blue_a700</item>
</style>

<style name="SeekbarStyle.Green" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar">
        <item name="android:progressBackgroundTint">@color/material_green_a700_pct_30</item>
        <item name="android:thumbTint">@color/material_green_a700</item>
        <item name="android:thumbTintMode">src_in</item>
        <item name="android:progressTint">@color/material_green_a700</item>
</style>
```

The above sets the Theme seekbar style to blue for all devices 21+ including Samsung (which need the seekBarStyle applied in addition to android:seekBarStyle; not sure why but I saw this issue firsthand). If you want all seekbars to keep the theme style and only apply the green seekbar style to a few widgets then add the following to the widget you want:

```
<SeekBar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Green"/>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also make it this way :

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/redSeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:progressDrawable="@color/red"
    android:maxHeight="3dip"/>
```

Hope it will help!

Comment: I don't think you can use a color where it's looking for a drawable