# Issue with custom seek bar in Android

Tags: android, progress, seekbar

[image][image]

I am having problem with custom seek bar I am not getting same as i expect, I am using 2nd image as progress drawable and first as thumb, but when i use wrap content it is small and when i use fill parent it is repeating and the seek bar different from the 2nd image in the UI?

Comment: Would you post your code ?

Comment: <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       
        
        android:max="100"
       
        android:progress="20"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/2ndimage"
        android:thumb="@drawable/1stimage" />

Comment: <SeekBar 
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:max="100" android:progress="20" 
android:progressDrawable="@drawable/2ndimage" android:thumb="@drawable/1stimage" />

Comment: Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Nine-path](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) graphics. With this android will automatically resize your image based on borders you provide in graphics.

Comment: I want seekbar size is same as progressdrawable (image2 ) size.
thank you :)

Comment: 9-patch strects all the image whatever you want.

Comment: Check this, http://tugrulasik.com/2013/07/14/9-patch-cizim-editorunun-kullanimi-wysiwyg-editor/

Comment: i know how to use 9 patches in this case it wont worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

set maxHeight and minHeight of seekbar properties.
example:

```
maxHeight = 40dp
minHeight = 40dp
```