# Visually looks like ratingbar But a SeekBar

Tags: android

### RatingBar gives the functionality ::

***It accepts value like*** `1`-`1.5`-`2`-`2.5`-`3`-`3.5`-`4`-`4.5`-`5`

representation::

[image]

**Code**::

```
<RatingBar
                android:id="@+id/RATINGinitialvalueratingID"
                style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/RATINGseekBarID"
                android:clickable="false"
                android:focusable="false"
                android:numStars="5"
                android:rating="0" />
```

---

### seekbar gives the functionality ::

***It accepts value like*** `1-2-3-4-5`

representation ::

[image]

```
<SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/RATINGseekBarID"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
                android:max="100" >
            </SeekBar>
```

**Java code for seekbar**

```
PRICEbar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.PRICEseekBarID); // make seekbar object
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this); 
        PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                    boolean fromUser) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                PRICEtextProgress = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.PRICEtextViewProgressID);
                PRICEtextProgress.setText("Price:: Rs "+progress);
                seekBar.setMax(100);

            }
        });
```

---

### Is it possible ?

### how to custom design rating bar that looks visually like seekbar. ?

**Hope i am clear**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This might help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar?rq=1).
It will give you the idea about how it works. You'll have to put a `png` file containing the `ratingbar` sort of design.