# My seekbar not showing correctly

Tags: android, android-seekbar

I have refered here : [Android - styling seek bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar)

and its working fine except some device how to solve this problem.

its showing like this
[image]

I want like this:

[image]