# Make my own custom component in Android

Tags: android, android-custom-view, custom-component

I drew two images in Photoshop (the first is the base of my fader and the second one is the cursor itself). I would like to combine these two images and add an event gesture to this component in order to create my own fader.

I read the "[Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html)" section of the API Guides of Android Developers but since I'm a newbie on Android, I'm a little bit lost in all these methods and classes (onDraw(), onMeasure(), ImageView class, etc.)

How would you create this fader?

Here are the two images and the image that show the final result: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B1Sk-uP_T-7KLXZtcUFhLVVrZVk&usp=sharing

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. Please add more detail.

Comment: This seems to be not a custom component, but a custom seekbar. Refer to this page for more information. [SO Page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar)

Comment: OK, I think it will be easier to use this class. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your screenshots, it seems that you are trying to achieve a custom `seekBar`, not a completely new component. Based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16165498/3463021), you can customize the `seekBar` with your own images instead of creating a new component.