# Adding color picker to canvas in android

Tags: android, android-layout

Am making on app where in am writing on image by touch using color picker(to pick a color) and a seek bar (to write in different size). I have successfully implemented the all the above features but my problem is am not able to get the canvas to full screen and when i get the canvas to full screen am not able to add the color picker and seek bar on to it.

**Main Layout**

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <com.colorpiker.ColorPicker
            android:id="@+id/picker"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:layout_gravity="left" />

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|right"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:max="40" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/save"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Save" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/signatureView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
 public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private SignatureView _signView ;
    private SeekBar seekBar;
    private Button save;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        _signView = new SignatureView(getApplicationContext(),"");

        save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save);
        save.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {


               try
               {

               long imgp = ActivityCamera.imagename;
               String imageName = String.valueOf(imgp);
               Bitmap well = _signView.getBitmap();
               String fileName = "/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Worpie/"+imageName + ".jpg";
               OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
               well.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 80, os);
               os.flush();
               os.close();

               }catch (NullPointerException e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Null error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "File error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               catch (IOException e) 
               {
                   e.printStackTrace();
                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IO error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

           }



        });
        seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(
        //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar
        new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            int progress = 10;
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progresValue, boolean fromUser) {
                progress = progresValue;
            }`enter code here`

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                writeText(progress);
            }
        });



        ColorPicker picker = (ColorPicker) findViewById(R.id.picker);
        picker.getColor();  
        picker.setOldCenterColor(picker.getColor());
        picker.setOnColorChangedListener(new OnColorChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onColorChanged(int color) {

                _signView.setNewColor(color);
            }
        });

        _signView.setNewColor(picker.getColor());
        LinearLayout _layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.signatureView);
        _layout.addView(_signView);

    }

    //============================
    public void  writeText(float stroke){
        _signView.setStroke(stroke);
    }
}
```

**SignatureView**

```
  package com.colorpiker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Path;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class SignatureView extends View {

    private Bitmap mBitmap, mybitmap;
    private Canvas mCanvas;
    private Path mPath;
    private Paint mBitmapPaint;
    private Paint mPaint;
    private float stroke;
    private String imageName;

    // 3 Constructors, covers instantiating manually or from a layout file
    public SignatureView(Context context, String imageName) {
        super(context);
        this.imageName = imageName;
        initSignatureView();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initSignatureView();
    }

    public SignatureView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defaultStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defaultStyle);
        initSignatureView();
    }

    public void setImageName(String imageName) {
        this.imageName = imageName;
    }
    protected void initSignatureView() {
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);

    }

    public void setStroke(float stroke) {
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(stroke);
    }

    public void setNewColor(int color) {
        mPaint.setColor(color);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        if (mBitmap == null) {
            long imgp = ActivityCamera.imagename;
            String imageName = String.valueOf(imgp);
            mybitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/mnt/sdcard/Pictures/Worpie/"+ imageName + ".jpg");
            mBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mybitmap, getMeasuredWidth(),getMeasuredHeight(), false);
            mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
            mPath = new Path();
            mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
        }
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint); // draw offscreen
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint); // draw current path

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);// commit the path to our offscreen
        mPath.reset();// kill this so we don't double draw
    }

    public Bitmap getBitmap()
    {

        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);  
        this.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(this.getDrawingCache());   
        this.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);


        return bmp;
    }

}
```