# Dynamic content android

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface, graphics

I have an app which calculates user BMI (Body Mass Index) based on inputs like weight and height. But I want to show results on a similar graph(?). For example, if the BMI result is between 18.5 & 24.9, the arrow comes to the green part. I totally have no idea on how to do this, so even very little guides would be useful for me.[see related image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgJgu.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use a customized Seekbar with a background (the BMI spectrum) and a custom indicator (the arrow). Pointers: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar) and [here](http://android-dev-examples.blogspot.it/2014/09/android-custom-seekbar.html)