# Custom SeekBar pressed background color

Tags: android, seekbar

I've spent a few hours on a `SeekBar` and I was able to customize it accordingly, except that there is a pressed background that insists in using my primary color (`colorAccent`).

I'm attaching a few pictures so I hope you can understand what I mean. I've messed with all the `SeekBar` methods and with `PorterDuff.MODE`'s, but no success so far.

[image: Clicking and pressing]
Clicking and pressing

[image: Clicking and pressing]
Clicking and pressing again

[image: Normal state, not clicking]
Normal state, not clicking

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: You can check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Comment: I've used exactly this question to build my custom SeekBar, however it doesn't address my issue

Answer (score 0):

You can start from here and then develop your own:

**XML**

```
<app.minimize.com.seek_bar_compat.SeekBarCompat
    android:id="@+id/mySeekBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxHeight="300sp"
    app:progressColor="#AFF123"
    app:progressBackgroundColor="#000"
    app:thumbColor="#FF4444"
    app:thumbAlpha="1.0"/>
```

you can also control it **programmatically**

```
SeekBarCompat seekBarCompat = (SeekBarCompat) findViewById(R.id.mySeekBar);
seekBarCompat.setThumbColor(Color.RED);
seekBarCompat.setProgressColor(Color.CYAN);
seekBarCompat.setProgressBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE); 
seekBarCompat.setThumbAlpha(128); //you can also set alpha value for the thumb
```

Don't forget to add the **Dependecy**

```
compile 'com.minimize.library:seekbar-compat:0.2.5'
```

I would also recommend you **to visit** [This link](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/83) for various styles of seekbars it is really helpful

Comment: Thanks, you're suggesting a third-party library, although that's not exactly what I asked