# Why doesn't the Switch added to tool bar pick up colors from styles.xml?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-switch, switchcompat

I am trying to add a switch to the tool bar. It is showing up, but the color of the switch is not getting picked up from **styles.xml**. What am I doing wrong?

**Home.java**

```
public class Home extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_home,menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

**HomeFragment.java**

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment {

public HomeFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
}
}
```

**home_activity.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.a.a2.Home">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_home" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**home_content.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fragment"
    android:name="com.a.a2.HomeFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
```

**home_fragment.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/content_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.a.a2.HomeFragment"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_home">

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu_home.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.a.a2.Home">


    <item
        android:id="@+id/onOff"
        android:title=""
        app:actionLayout="@layout/switch_layout"
        app:showAsAction="always" />

</menu>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/tools" xmlns:app="urn:oasis:names:tc:xliff:document:1.2">

  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/actionMenuTextColor</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyToolbar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#000000</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ToolbarTitle" parent="@style/TextAppearance.Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Title">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    </style>

    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <style name="onOffSwitch" >
        <!-- active thumb & track color (30% transparency) -->
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#D32F2F</item>

        <item name="colorControlNormal">#D32F2F</item>

        <!-- inactive thumb color -->
        <item name="colorSwitchThumbNormal">#009688</item>

        <!-- inactive track color (30% transparency)#42221f1f -->
        <item name="android:colorForeground">#303F9F</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**SwitchLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <android.support.v7.widget.SwitchCompat
        app:theme="@style/onOffSwitch"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/switch1"
        android:checked="true"
        android:soundEffectsEnabled="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="25dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

1) Why isn' the colors from styles.xml not picked up?
2) The Switch is mentioned in Switch_layout. But it is not mentioned in menu.xml or else, how come it is being shown when I run the app?
2a) Shouldn't there be a reference to switch_layout in some other xml or java code?

I am doing as per this answer

[How to change the color of a SwitchCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26714864/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-switchcompat)

and

[How to change the track color of a SwitchCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27845595/how-to-change-the-track-color-of-a-switchcompat/27879897#27879897)

PS:

[image]

I would like to change the gradient of the place that I have arrowed.

Comment: ColorAccent is what you should look into
Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40945414/how-to-change-seekbar-color/40945545#40945545) out

Comment: But I want different color for thumb normal, when it is on, when it is off and for the trace area of switch widget?

Comment: @shadygoneinsane Could you answer other questions please?