# how to change SeekBar color in android? (Programmatically)

Tags: java, android, seekbar

I made an equalizer to go with my app but I am not sure how I can change the seekbar's thumb and progress color. It seems to be pink by default and that doesn't fit my app's aesthetics.

```
 SeekBar seekBar = new SeekBar(this);

        seekBar.setId(i);

        seekBar.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        seekBar.setMax(upperEqualizerBandLevel - lowerEqualizerBandLevel);

        seekBar.setProgress(mEqualizer.getBandLevel(equalizerBandIndex));
        //seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
        //seekBar.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

Comment: To change in layout see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To change the color of the `Seekbar` thumb, create a new style in `style.xml`

```
<style name="SeekBarColor"
  parent="Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"> 
  <item name="colorAccent">@color/your_color</item> 
</style>
```

Finally in the layout:

```
<SeekBar
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:theme="@style/SeekBarColor" />
```

To change the `Seekbar` progress color, use this in Java Class.

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter("yourcolor", PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Both these will work for API>16.

**Edit**

To change SeekBar thumb color by Java code.

```
 seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getCo‌​lor(R.color.your_color‌​), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the latter since i made the seekbars for the equalizer programmatically.  The progress color changes but i am unable to change the thumb. Anything i can do about that?

Comment: The first part of the answers states how to change color of seekbar thumb. I have added this code since it runs over a wider API range.

Comment: Check the edited answer for Java code to change seekbar thumb color(works only for android 5 and above).

Comment: deprecated in high api levels

Answer (score 7):

While using a style is a good idea, it does not provide much flexibility specially if you want to assign the colors programmatically I suggest:

`//for the progress 
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(mThemeColor,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
//for the thumb handle
seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(mThemeColor, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);`

Answer (score 1):

You can change seekbar thumb and progress colors for programmatically like this:

```
   seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(Utils.getAccentColor(this), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
   seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(Utils.getAccentColor(this), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can easily change it via code,

For example:

```
seekbar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.parseColor(#000000)));
```

or

```
seekbar.setProgressTintList(ColorStateList.valueOf(Color.RED));
```

Hoping that it will be helpfull for someone in future.

Comment: It has been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call you seekbar like this

```
SeekBar newSeek = new SeekBar(this, null, R.style.YOUR_NEW_STYLE);
```

where `YOUR_NEW_STYLE` will define the colors of the `Seekbar` that you want.

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(R.color.mcolor), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Comment: this does not change the thumb

Answer (score 0):

Just a little more peachy answer

```
public static void setSeekBarColor(SeekBar seekBar, int color) {
    seekBar.getProgressDrawable().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
    seekBar.getThumb().setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version, and without using deprecated methods:

```
val colorFilter = BlendModeColorFilterCompat.createBlendModeColorFilterCompat(
    Resources.getSystem().getColor(R.color.your_color, null),
    BlendModeCompat.SRC_ATOP
)

// SeekBar progress color
seekBar.progressDrawable.colorFilter = colorFilter
// SeekBar thumb handle color
seekBar.thumb.colorFilter = colorFilter
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    //seekBar.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    //seekBar.setDrawingCacheBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
```

There are few Views in Android SDK (ProgressBar is another example) in which you have to change colour using graphical color filters, instead of changing Background / Foreground source colour.

Find `.setColorFilter()` method, supply your source colour into it with some PorterDuff filter, like `.Mode.MULTIPLY` (depending on what filter mode you like best) and there you go.

Example:

```
seekBar.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(srcColor,PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY));
```