# How to change color of seekbar setProgressDrawable programmatically

Tags: java, android-seekbar

I have a seekbar in my adapter class and 3 buttons. When I press button one by one, I want to change seekbar progress according to buttons.

```
if (pos==0){
    viewholder.binding.quizNameTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color._495A87));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setThumb(ViewUtil.setSeekbarThumb(context,R.color._495A87));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_seekbar_joyscore_progress));
}
else if(pos==1){
    viewholder.binding.quizNameTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color._83CBC2));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setThumb(ViewUtil.setSeekbarThumb(context,R.color._83CBC2));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_seekbar_biomescore_progress));
}
else {
    viewholder.binding.quizNameTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color._EF8470));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setThumb(ViewUtil.setSeekbarThumb(context,R.color._EF8470));
    viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_seekbar_joyurth_progress));
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to change SeekBar color in android? (Programmatically)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45329174/how-to-change-seekbar-color-in-android-programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

**I Solved My Problem , I just put 3rd line in 1st placed**

viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setProgressDrawable(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.quiz_seekbar_joyscore_progress));

viewholder.binding.quizNameTv.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color._495A87));
viewholder.binding.quizSeekbar.setThumb(ViewUtil.setSeekbarThumb(context,R.color._495A87));