# SeekBar color not obeying the style colorAccent

Tags: android, material-design

I configure my style as follows:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
</style>
```

In my simulator and in my Note 8, I see the SeekBars correctly drawn in black.
But in my old Galaxy S5, I see them in some palid blue-green.

The seekbar declaration is here, just positional information:

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/percentage_seekbar"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="26dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

This is how the SeekBar looks like instead of black:

[image]

This is how I expect it to be and how I see it in emulator and Note 8:

[image]

This are the contents of my manifest file:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

I don't know where else to look into to fix it... is it a matter of API version?

Comment: Can you include the layout that includes the seekbars and/or screenshots from both devices?

Comment: I did it. Thanks!

Comment: Look at this post here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar

Comment: @Aaron in fact I tried to declare a custom layout for the seekBar and again, it works on emulator and Note 8, but not on Galaxy S5.... weird... I used one of the examples of this web https://android-dev-examples.blogspot.ch/2014/09/android-custom-seekbar.html