# Seekbar change tick mark color on progress

Tags: android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have discrete `seekbar` on which I want to change color of custom made tick marks as well on progress but I was unable to find solution for that. I have read that there is a bug in `AppCompatSeekbar` which makes tick marker in front of the `thumb` but idea here is to change the color of tick marker on progress color change.

> Right now progress is in green color but when it reaches tick mark,
>   tick mark stays grey it is not changing its color to green.

Is possible to change tick mark color on progress and if so how could I achieve that? Thanks in advance.

Here you can see attached image which will make things more clearer I believe:

[image]

Comment: Ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @MidasLefko unfortunately not, we just left it like that.

Comment: @Yupi check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163215/android-styling-seek-bar .The answers there might can help in your case